# Can't convert to integer number coming from .csv file

Tags: php, excel, csv

I'm putting the data from a .csv file into an array, but the numbers come as strings. When I try to convert them back to integer, they become `0`. Code I'm using to get the data from the .csv file:

```
$reportData = [];
$file = fopen('DailyReport.csv','r');
while(!feof($file)){
   $reportData[] = fgetcsv($file,NULL,'|');
}
```

I tried to convert the numbers using:

```
foreach($reportData as $res){
   $int[] = intval($res[0]);
   //or
   $int[] = (int)$res[0];
   //or even
   $int[] = $res[0]*1;
```

None of that works, any ideas why?

The values of `$res[0]` are always integers. When I run `var_dump($res[0]);` the results are:

```
string(15) "1437961"
string(15) "1437971"
string(15) "1438127"
string(15) "1440392"
string(15) "1440394"
string(15) "1440399"
string(15) "1440924"
string(15) "1440986"
```

And var_dump(bin2hex($res[0])) returns:

```
string(30) "003100340033003700390036003100"
string(30) "003100340033003700390037003100"
string(30) "003100340033003800310032003700"
string(30) "003100340034003000330039003200"
string(30) "003100340034003000330039003400"
string(30) "003100340034003000330039003900"
string(30) "003100340034003000390032003400"
string(30) "003100340034003000390038003600"
```

Comment: Please `var_dump($res[0])` and show us the result.

Comment: Likely you're casting non-numerical strings as integer, despite you think you are.

Comment: I put the results of var_dump($res[0]), you can see the values are all integers

Comment: See? You have strings in there. But I'm convinced its not the whole truth. Please output `var_dump(bin2hex($res[0]));` to show if there are hidden characters which might mess with your integer conversion

Comment: `string(15) "1437961"`.... I only count 7 visible characters.... is this a dual byte encoding?

Comment: Looks like the .csv file is UTF-16 encoded. If that is accidental, you can change the encoding in an editor.

Comment: I converted the csv file to utf-8 manually and it seems to be working. But the csv will keep coming to me in other format, so I need to convert it with php, any ideas how to do that?

Comment: It should be possible to apply a context to the file when you open it that converts utf-16 to utf-8

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to convert the encoding of the strings read from the CSV file using the [mbstring](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) module.

First reading the file:

```
$reportData = [];
$file = fopen('DailyReport.csv', 'r');
while(!feof($file)) {
   $reportData[] = fgetcsv($file, NULL, '|');
}
```

Your `var_dump(bin2hex(...))` output suggests that DailyReport.csv is in UTF-16BE. (There are two bytes per digit, and the *leading* byte is always a zero. A *trailing* zero byte would suggest UTF-16LE.)

Let's convert these big endian UTF-16 strings to UTF-8 using `mbstring`, and then to integers:

```
foreach($reportData as $res) {
   $resUTF8 = mb_convert_encoding($res[0], 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE');
   $resInt = intval($resUTF8);
   echo $resInt, PHP_EOL;    // <- we have actual integers here
 }
```

A possible disadvantage here is that the `mbstring` module may not be enabled by default... Alternatively, we could use [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php), but it can be a little bit capricious at times.

Comment: Was UTF-8 BOM in my case but this was the vital clue. Thanks.